# How to test 'didFocus' from react navigation with jest

Tags: react-native, jestjs, react-navigation

I have a component that looks like this

```
async componentDidMount() {
    const { navigation } = this.props
    this.subs = [
      navigation.addListener('didFocus', () => this.onComponentFocus()),
    ]
  }

  onComponentFocus() {
    const { dispatch } = this.props
    dispatch(fetchDevices())
  }
```

Now i want to write a test that chekcs fetchDevice got called once. The first idea was to mock Navigation like this

const navigation = {
  navigate: jest.fn(),
}

But now how do I check this.subs and how do i check fetchDevices got fired?

Comment: it depends on where `fetchDevices()` comes from

Answer (score 4):

If we suppose that `fetchDevices` comes from a library

**`Component.spec.js`**

```js
import fetchDevices from 'device-fetcher';
jest.mock('device-fetcher');

// as your component accepts the dispatch function
// you can create it as mock function
const mockDispatch = jest.fn();

// since in your implementation you're calling navigation.addListener
const mockNavigation = {
  navigate: jest.fn(),
  // it should also have 
  addListener: jest.fn()
};

describe('Component', () => {

  const wrapper = shallow(<Component navigation={mockNavigation} dispatch={mockDispatch} />);

  describe('navigation didFocus', () => {
    beforeAll(() => {
      // get .addEventListener calls with 'didFocus'
      mockNavigation.addEventListener.mock.calls
        .filter(([eventName]) => eventName === 'didFocus')
        // iterate over the "attached" handlers
        .map(([eventName, eventHandler]) => {
          // and trigger them
          eventHandler();
        });
    });

    it('should have called the dispatch with the result of fetchDevices', () => {
      expect(mockDispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
        fetchDevices.mock.results[0].value
      );
    });
  });
});
```

note: it's not tested, just a solution outline

---

**edit:** if the `fetchDevices` is a property instead of mocking the library you define a mock function

```
const fetchDevices = jest.fn();

// and pass it to the component
shallow(<Component navigation={mockNavigation} dispatch={mockDispatch} fetchDevices={fetchDevices} />);
```

and then you should have the same assertions for it

Comment: Hi sorry testDevices is an action.  What i want to test is that test devices runs when the app opens.  The external library is what hooks onComponentFocus to componentDidMount